# Is this a jquery conflict, or would this be some other type of issue on my WordPress domain?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css

I have a WordPress domain that just doesn't function properly -- none of my plugins work properly after, say, 5 or 6 hours after I fix things.

Oddly, the only thing I do to fix things is to **add or take out something from the < head >**  section.  I could take out or add google analytics, a Facebook script, and then it's good for a couple of hours and I have to do it again.

The only thing I saw that may be improper is this in my html output:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://www.occupyhln.org/wp-includes
/js/jquery/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Is that, in effect, double-loading jquery and thus causing jquery issues?

Here is the homepage when things look normal:

[image: Homepage - Good]

Here is a page, a couple hours later, no changes, when things don't look normal:

[image: Website - Bad]

I realize I'm not giving much in the way of code here.  I'm using a pricy framework and child theme and I've even tried deactivating plugins, but to no avail.

But just based on what I can give, is it possible to tell if this is a jquery conflict, or perhaps a CSS type of conflict?  I'm truly baffled, and any guidance to help push me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any errors in your console? Btw, you should use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script for enqueueing JQuery.

Comment: Thanks RRikesh ... embarrassingly, I've been told that there were errors in my console, but I'm unsure as to how about locating them.  Any guidance in that regard would be appreciated -- and I'd gladly report right back!

Comment: I'm using Catalyst framework with Dynamik child theme, so it's slightly different ...

Comment: Install Firebug or Firebug lite depending on your browser. Modern browsers already have something similar though.

Comment: Yes ... I have firebug and Chrome developer tools, but I'll see what I can find in Firebug ...

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin of some kind? Something that turns bad a while after you've fixed it can often be some kind of subtle caching problem. For example, I made a mistake on my site that would only show up for non-logged in users. It worked fine when I viewed the site, but at some point later, the broken page was re-cached by a visit from a non-logged-in user, and so looked broken when I went back to view it, too.

Comment: Hi Matt.  Thanks for responding.  I'm using WP Super Cache, and have "Cache for known users" unchecked ... but I also test it out on my desktop right next to me, and have others online check ... so I'm not sure if it's the caching plugin doing it or some type of jquery conflict or perhaps even a CSS conflict ... will check into things!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<script src="http://www.occupyhln.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js">\x3C/script>
```

instead

```
<script src="http://www.occupyhln.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"><\/script>
```

i replaced

`</script>`  with `\x3C/script>`

Comment: Thank you Kanishka ... I'm attempting to find out where that line of html output is being called from so I can test that change!